# Spark Sql - Running twice

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I come across spark code for ETL process, in that code long complex sql statements are written and  facing oom error and sometime single job takes 4 hours with multple execution of same code.

They have many etl processes like this and i pasted the example query here with long complex joins with nesting and aggregation, group by, ordr by etc.  Btw still it is not full query

Please look at below query and they are using it as

```
SqlContext.sql(below query).write.mode(append).insertinto(hivetbl)
```

Is this the right way of utilizing spark ??

---

```
SELECT 
    above 30 joins with aggregations
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try breaking the SQL into multiple fragments? Probably one join per fragment?

1. take a join write the output into parquet file
2. join the output with another table and dump it into parquet file
3. repeat the above.

Joins in big-data are distributed and have a lot of assumptions underlying. Incidentally, for your use-case, `prestodb` seems to be the right fit.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Spark infers the type of column by running the user's query with an empty result. (check out https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala line 112, getSchemaQuery function)

Simple queries like (select ... from ...) where 1=0 would be super fast, but the queries that has join operation will be slow as much as join operation works.

Maybe you can use (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) "customSchema" option to prevent spark infer your types of result.